# HIVE - Format of time difference

Tags: hadoop, time, hive

I want to calculate the difference between to events. Both events are stored in the UNIX_TIMESTAMP in miliseconds.

Here is an example: 1464740049000

How can I convert the time difference and format them in hours.

I tried several things like datediff and/or timestamp(event1) - timestamp(event2).

What I want is

> select timestamp(e1.time), timestamp(e2.time), e1.time-e2.time as
>   Time_Diff from testdata;

Time_Diff should be formatted in hours, minutes, seconds... 
How can I get this?
Thanks in advance
Peter

Answer (score 1):

If the difference is less than 24 hours, you can use this:

```
[localhost:21000] > select from_unixtime(1392394861 - 1392394860, 'HH:mm:ss');
+----------------------------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1392394861 - 1392394860, 'hh:mm:ss') |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 00:00:01                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

If the difference can be more than 24 hours, the following rather ugly expression will do the trick:

```
[localhost:21000] > select concat(cast(floor((1392394861 - 1392300000)/60/60) as string), from_unixtime(1392394861 - 1392300000, ':mm:ss'));
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat(cast(floor((1392394861 - 1392300000) / 60 / 60) as string), from_unixtime(1392394861 - 1392300000, ':mm:ss')) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 26:21:01                                                                                                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Or if you prefer a format with explicit days:

```
[localhost:21000] > select concat(cast(floor((1392394861 - 1392300000)/60/60/24) as string), " days and ", from_unixtime(1392394861 - 1392300000, 'HH:mm:ss'));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat(cast(floor((1392394861 - 1392300000) / 60 / 60 / 24) as string), ' days and ', from_unixtime(1392394861 - 1392300000, 'hh:mm:ss')) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 days and 02:21:01                                                                                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The "ugly expression" works fine! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in Hour only, Instead of converting the unixtimestamp to timestamp, just use SQL Mathematical functions

```
select (time2 - time1)/(1000 * 60 * 60) as hours from mytable;
```